# Add datetime type information to a post that I voted on

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, voting, upvotes

Would it be possible to have somewhere the information on when we upvoted or downvoted a post (in case of post was edited by OP or someone else)? For example, see the tooltip below.

[image]

It's a feature I've been missing for a long time, because when I come back years later to a post and see that I've voted up or down, I wish I had known at what point in my career I needed this information...

Comment: If its been some time since your vote and there's been no edit since, you can try to undo your vote which will give you an error message with the date and time when you voted.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Show timestamp of a vote in the tooltip when mousing over it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176503/show-timestamp-of-a-vote-in-the-tooltip-when-mousing-over-it)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat agree with you, so my feature request is in case of question was edited by OP or someone. Your link is exactly wat I asked

Comment: The initial vote only? There are posts I keep rediscovering every few months, then click upvote before realising I already did that the last couple of times…

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, indeed, agree for all posts.

Comment: Is there a way to someone at top hierarchy or moderator consider this request ?