# How can we easily find when we upvoted something (not recent?)

Tags: support

I had a low-priority question bouncing around in my mind. I forgot if I'd asked before--I hadn't written it in my small Python cheat sheet. The answer was here: [Split a string by spaces -- preserving quoted substrings -- in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79968/split-a-string-by-spaces-preserving-quoted-substrings-in-python), and I noticed, when I got there, I had already upvoted it!

I was slightly amused by this and also curious when the upvote happened. Looking into a repo I had, I simply typed `git log -Sshlex` to see the date. (2 years ago!)

But I'm wondering if there's a search-fu via StackOverflow, to parse through my kind-of-long voting history. Searching by tags doesn't help, since the two tags (python and regex) are pretty common. I guess I could put a search in my browser for the topic title and then scroll through the pages of votes and hit F3, but that's a lot of clicking!

This is mostly for curiosity and historical reference and, of course, git can come to the rescue when I actually implemented the knowledge I upvoted.

I noticed an anonymized voting summary at, say, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/79968/timeline, but this doesn't help me set when I first stumbled on the topic.

Comment: The easiest way is to try and remove your vote. If it's not been edited since it'll tell you when you voted... although sometimes this will just remove your vote :-)

Comment: I tried to solve this with SEDE, but straightforward approaches do not work. It appears that, in the `Votes` table, the `UserID` column does not actually get populated.

Comment: Yes, that is intentional @KarlKnechtel as votes are private. It would defeat the point if you could get that data from SEDE or the data dump.

Comment: Related feature request: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423837/add-datetime-type-information-to-a-post-that-i-voted-on